# How to add a Apply For Job button with links and photos to Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Our Facebook Page is to be used as a recruiting tool and we want to add an app that takes the user to a page with links to our website, similar to this: http://www.facebook.com/KPMGinAustraliaGraduatesandStudents/app_7146470109

I have searched Facebook help to cutomize Notes and to find a list of apps but had no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create your own. That is not a note, it is a custom tab application.

See http://developers.facebook.com for more information.